# React: Why does Babel not polyfill String.prototype.replaceAll?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Having read that React takes care of setting up Babel and webpack for me, I used the new (ES2020 or ES2021?) [String.prototype.replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) function in my code, assuming it would be polyfilled by Babel for unsupported browsers, but it isn't.

Is there extra config I can add to make Babel do this polyfill? Adding extra config seems to be against the philosophy of create-react-app.

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/ - CRA doesn't support all post-ES6 language features and doesn't polyfill.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, following a link in the documentation he pointed to to [react-app-polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md).

I added the react-app-polyfill node module to my app, and added:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

to my index.js file. This will, hopefully, do some polyflling for older browsers, but there's no polyfill for String.prototype.replaceAll(), and I haven't been able to test if it does actually help older browsers use my site that wouldn't otherwise be able to.

Comment: In order to get only selected polyfills (e.g. String.prototype.replaceAll), see https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/.  You can drop a <script> tag into your primary page that pulls in just the ones you find missing.

Comment: `import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';` doesn't seem to polyfill `replaceAll()`